# Laravel Mix always include jQuery

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I use Laravel 5.6, with Mix. I want to load a plugin which uses jQuery to my project.

I created a **fileuploader.js** file :

```
// see more at http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#installation

import 'bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput';
import 'bootstrap-fileinput/js/locales/fr';
```

It loads a npm package. In my **webpack.mix.js**, I have :

```
mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery']
});

mix
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/fileuploader.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/plugins/fileuploader.scss', 'public/css')
;

mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/img', 'public/img');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

In my **app.js**, I have :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
import './bootstrap';

$(function() {
  // some jQuery code
});
```

I removed this line from **bootstrap.js** file :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

But when I take a look to /js/fileuploader.js file generated with Webpack, it sill loads the full jQuery code.

The result in my template is :

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8000/js/fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input[type="file"]').fileinput({
            language: 'fr',
            uploadUrl: '/upload',
        });
    })
</script>
```

And I got this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fileinput is not a function

I suppose it's because jQuery (version 3.3.1) is loaded 2 times in both JS files. How can I prevent this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try removing

```
mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery']
});
```